# $ operator is invalid for atomic vectors in r

Tags: r, linear-regression

I am trying to calculate squared residual mean for a model. But I keep getting the error

> Error in error$residuals : $ operator is invalid for atomic vectors.

[image: sample data]

```
  attach(delivery_time)

  plot(log(`Sorting Time`), `Delivery Time`)

  cor(log(`Sorting Time`), `Delivery Time`)

  reg <- lm(`Delivery Time` ~ log(`Sorting Time`))

  summary(reg)

  deliveryer <- predict(reg)

  errordelivery <- exp(deliveryer)


  deliverytime = delivery_time$`Delivery Time`- errordelivery

  deliverytime$residuals

  sqrt(mean(deliverytime$residuals^2))
```

> **Error in deliverytime$residuals : 
>         $ operator is invalid for atomic vectors**

Comment: Is `deliverytime$residuals` actually a vector of residuals? I'm guessing there's a problem with that object.

Comment: `sqrt(mean(mtcars$cyl^2))` is valid, so there's something specific to your object that makes this throw an error

Comment: The easiest way for us to help is if you can add the output of `dput(head(deliverytime))` to your question

Comment: @Mako212 
  thank you for your response.. as per your recommendation, executed the above command..   
  c(`1` = -3524176131.1506, `2` = -887799.659558213, `3` = 
  -34736606.8351164, 
  `4` = -1359107141.19933, `5` = -3524176123.1506, `6` = 
  -34736611.2351164
  )

Comment: This code works then, right? `sqrt(mean(deliverytime^2))`

Comment: Delivery time is not a `data.frame` therefore `deliverytime$residuals` is meaningless, since there is no column to access with `$`.

Comment: When you do `deliverytime = delivery_time$\`Delivery Time\`- errordelivery` you create a new object named `deliverytime`. The string "residuals" isn't mentioned anywhere. Perhaps you want to add a column named `residuals`  to the `delivery_time` data frame? Then do this: `delivery_time$residuals = delivery_time$\`Delivery Time\`- errordelivery`. Make sure you use the `_` in the name, otherwise you've got a new object.

Comment: @Mako212..sqrt(mean(deliverytime^2)) works..sorry. i am trying to calculate residuals for error..u are right. it is not a data.frame. thank you

Comment: @AbhiRamchallapalli since you took a log of your input variable (Sorting Time) only, you don't need to take the exp of the predict. that step is only necessary if you take the log of the y variable! reg$residuals will give you the residuals.

Comment: @shirin. thank you..